# MySQL and Hive query Implementation

Tags: mysql, join, hadoop, hive, where-clause

I would like to have a better understanding of how queries are implemented in hive or MySQL to optimize them for runtime savings.

Suppose I am doing an INNER JON operations on two tables on key "name" and I only want row where name is equal to "random"

```
SELECT * from tbl1 JOIN tbl2 on tbl2.name = tbl1.name where tbl1.name = 'random';
```

Now in the implementation what would be the sequence of events:
1. Is it filtering on tbl1 for name="random" followed by a JOIN operation?
2. Is it JOIN on tables then filtering based on name="random"?

I think option 1 is better since we will be dealing with less data to JOIN and it should be faster. Any thoughts from experts?

UPDATE1:

Will the answer be the same if I modify my query to this:

```
(SELECT * FROM tbl1 where tbl1.name='random) tbl1_1 JOIN tbl2 on tbl2.name=tbl1_1.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. First filtering on tbl1 for name="random" will be done followed by a JOIN operation. This will prevent join from joining unnecessary records

You can use the EXPLAIN keyword to get the execution plan

Comment: How about if I modify my query to this: '(SELECT * FROM tbl1 where tbl1.name='random) tbl1_1 JOIN tbl2 on tbl2.name=tbl1_1.name'

Comment: thanks! You mean both queries (see my update) are equivalent. I will wait for some more time...and then accept your ans